# JavaScript link leads to random url

Tags: javascript, html, css, url, hyperlink

I was wondering how it is possible to create a link in HTML css and JavaScript that leads to one of three random URLs. Example: When you click the link, it will randomly lead you to either hi.html, hi2.html, or hi3.html. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: can you add more info please because i dont understand what do you want ?

Comment: Put the URLs in an array. Use a click event listener that picks a random element of the array and puts it into `this.href`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use put all three urls in an array then use `Math.random()` to generate an index. You can use anything as a seed for the random function (current timestamp for example).

```
// your button
<button onclick='navigate()`>Click Here</button>

// your javascript
const Urls = ['hi.html', 'hi2.html', 'hi3.html'];

function navigate () {
    // Math.Random() * 3 generates a floating point number between [0, 3)
    // Math.floor() converts the decimal number into an integer
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    
    // Use the url anywhere
    window.location = Urls[random];
}
```

[Example on how to create a random number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values)